# List within a Dictionary as Value in <Key-Value> Pair

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I am a newbie to Python and was reading up about dictionaries from the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html) and came across the following scenario :

> - Let us say ,  that there exists a dictionary  : **`{'x':[0,0,70,100,...] , 'y':[0,20,...] , ...}`**
> - I want to get hold of the `value` *(which happens to be a list here)* for each `key`
> - Then , I wish to play around with the elements of the list like make some comparisons among the values of the list  etc.
> - I wish to do this task `dynamically` i.e. using a `loop`
> - At present I can do it `statically` i.e. by `hard-coding` it but that does not take me anywhere

***Expected Input***

> **`{'pikachu':[200,50,40,60,70] , 'raichu':[40 ,30,20,10,140] , ....}`**

***Expected Output***

> **`{pikachu:[1,0,0,0] , raichu:[0,0,0,1] , .....}`**

***My Wish :***

I want to compare the elements of the `value` *(which is a `list` here)* pairwise : `(200,50);(50,40);(40,60);(60,70)` for each of the keys

The comparison is of the form :

```
   if(abs(x-x+1) > 20):
       then this event is marked as 1 
   else: 
       it is marked as 0
```

***My Code till now :***

```
import random   

def do_stuff():

  NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 5      

  list_of_pokemon = ['pikachu', 'charizard', 'sabertooth' , 'raichu'] 

  dict_of_pokemon = {}              

  for i in list_of_pokemon:         
    dict_of_pokemon[i] = [random.randrange(0, 200,10) for j in range(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS)]


  #This just prints out a dict of the form : {'pikachu':[200,50,40,60,70] , .....}
  print dict_of_pokemon 

  dict_of_changes = {}

  temp = []

  for x in dict_of_pokemon:

    for y in dict_of_pokemon[x]:
        # I wish to compare the elements of a value list 
        # For example : pairwise comparing (200,50);(50,40);(40,60);(60,70)
```

***My Question:***

Can Someone help me out ?

`*P.S. This is not a homework question*`

Comment: Hi , why has this been downvoted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def identify_events(seq):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(seq)-1):
        current = seq[i]
        next = seq[i+1]
        if abs(current - next) > 20:
            result.append(1)
        else:
            result.append(0)
    return result


d = {
    'pikachu':[200,50,40,60,70] , 
    'raichu':[40 ,30,20,10,140]
} 

output = {key: identify_events(value) for key, value in d.iteritems()}

print output
```

Result:

```
{'pikachu': [1, 0, 0, 0], 'raichu': [0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin - I think this does it :)

Answer (score 2):

Compact version:

```
d = {'pikachu': [200, 50, 40, 60, 70], 'raichu': [40, 30, 20, 10, 140]}

print {k: map(lambda x,y: 1 if abs(x-y)>20 else 0, v[:-1],v[1:]) 
              for k,v in d.iteritems()}

{'pikachu': [1, 0, 0, 0], 'raichu': [0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
lst = [200,50,40,60,70]
def pairwise_map(l):
    pairs = zip(l[:-1], l[1:])
    cond = lambda x: abs(x[0] - x[1]) > 20
    return map(lambda x: 1 if cond(x) else 0, pairs)
print pairwise_map(lst)
```

Applying `pairwise_map` to the dictionary:

```
d = {
    'pikachu':[200,50,40,60,70] , 
    'raichu':[40 ,30,20,10,140]
} 

result = {k: pairwise_map(v) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
print result
```

Output:

```
{'pikachu': [1, 0, 0, 0], 'raichu': [0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

Following the comments, you may want to read about the very common [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), [lambdas](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: @pranav `lambda` is a "normal programming construct". We're not here to teach you to code, we're here to fix problems.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to compare each entry of your dictionary with all other entries. First, create a list of all pairs to compare, and then use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to have pairs of subsequent elements:

```
import itertools

keys = dict_of_pokemon.keys()
for key1,key2 in itertools.product(keys, keys):
    if key1 == key2:
        continue           # I assume you don't want to compare the same lists

    elements_to_compare = zip(dict_of_pokemons[key1], dict_of_pokemons[key2])

    print elements_to_compare # e.g. [(200,50), (50,40), (40,60), (60,70)]
```